# Turtlebot bringup minimal.launch, cannot find create on dev/ttyUSB0

Tags: ros, create, turtlebot-bringup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Every day I start up my turtlebot, I have the same problem with minimal.launch. Every day, I have to fix it, seemingly through random chance. I get it working, but it takes a significant amount of time everyday. I've looked through every post on the subject many times, and have added rules to give permissions to udev, but every day I have the same problem and simply have to get lucky in reboot.

Even if the create USB is assigned USB0, sometimes it doesn't work.

Can I go in and change the minimal launch so that it's looking for a SYNNAME for create instead of just looking at ttyUSB0?

Then making a rule in udev/rules.d like this:

KERNEL=="ttyUSB*", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0403", SYSFS{idProduct}=="6001", SYSFS{serial}==SERIAL_OF_USB_CABLE, SYMLINK+="turtlebot"

So my real question is if I do this in minimal.launch, are there going to be problems in the code later where instead of looking for turtlebot, the code is simply looking for ttyUSB0.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29788/turtlebot-bringup-minimal.launch,-cannot-find-create-on-dev/ttyusb0/) by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-03-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-03-16**:
Are you stopping the turtlebot service before running minimal.launch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [turtlebot_node](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_node) has a parameter for what the port is.  You will have to modify the launch file to set that parameter differently if you want to change the port name.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1